# Socket IO CPU peaks on production

Tags: node.js, performance, socket.io

I use Socket IO to do some realtime stuff. When i run the app on production i notice a high CPU. The CPU is not 100%, but it has peaks of 70%. I did some debugging and i noticed it has something to do with the number of users on the site. When there are more users on the site, the CPU usage get's higher.

I removed some listeners on the server side of SocketIO, then the CPU get's lower. It has something to do with the number of connections.

Does anyone know how i can improve this?

Comment: How many users are you talking about that are connected at once?  And, how often are you sending or receiving a message to each one?

Comment: When i open google analytics it is showing most of time 100 users, it's an platform where user's get notified every 10 seconds. So i will send messages a lot.

Comment: Well, that's not that many messages to send (1 every 10th of a second).  You'll have to profile your code and see where the time is being spent.